# Checking to numbers within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting confused as to why I cannot have a if statement within the for statement,

Going to try and clear this up sorry for not being clear.

```
lists = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
userList = []
for i in range(5):
    userList.append(input("Please enter a number :"))
for L in userList:
     if L in lists:
        print("It is in it")
    else:
        print("It is NOT in it")
```

I would like it to print "It is in it" should a number from userList be in lists.

So any number the user enters between 1 and 6 will print "It is in it".

Also sorry for saying python 2, my mistake.

Comment: You aren't using python 3. If you were you would only be getting `"It is not in it"` because `input()` returns a string in python 3

Comment: You also aren't using this exact code, otherwise you'd be getting `It is NOT in it` rather than `it is not in it`.

Comment: I tried your code, and it works for me ...

Comment: But what exactly is the problem?  It seems to me that the `if` within the `for` works just fine ...

Comment: Even if you are not using this exact code, what is your question? what is wrong with your example output?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear, i looked over it after i got a drink and saw my mistakes after it had already been down voted. Sorry I hope i fixed this.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()` returns a string, not an int as you expected in the code.

Use this

```
userList.append(int(input("Please enter a number :")))
```

The `int()` will convert the string to an int.

Comment: This doesn't matter since the comparison made by the `in` statement will compare int values as strings

Comment: @ibi0tux Actually it won't. The reason it works on Python 2.x only is the `input()` is effectively doing an `eval()` on the string. In Python 3.x, the code will fail.

Comment: @ibi0tux -- incorrect.  `"1" in (1,2,3)` will return `False`.

Comment: You might want to mention that this is a change in the behavior from the `input` function in python 2.x

Comment: I said this according to @jack is using Python 2.x.
I know the behaviour is different in python 3

Comment: Yes sorry i meant to add python 3. My mistake I hit the wrong one.

Comment: @ibi0tux either way, your assertion that "the comparison made by the `in` statement will compare int values as strings" is a little misleading.

Answer (score 1):

A version that would work in both Python2.X and python3.x ... somehow more complex.

```
lists = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
userList = []
for i in range(5):
    userList.append(input("Please enter a number :"))

print lists
print userList

for L in map(lambda x:int(x),userList):
    if L in map(lambda x:int(x),lists):
        print(L," is in it")
    else:
        print(L," is NOT in it")
```

Output :

```
Please enter a number :1
Please enter a number :3
Please enter a number :5
Please enter a number :7
Please enter a number :8
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8]
1  is in it
3  is in it
5  is in it
7  is NOT in it
8  is NOT in it
```

It prints exactly what you want.

Comment: But this script will fail on python3.x

Comment: Yes sorry my bad again i meant to use python 3.x damn tags. My mistake.

Comment: @jack : this version should work in both 2.x and 3.x